# I'm making an api in Nestjs where i can extract data from images but tesseract is showing errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, nestjs

In the following code I used multer for file upload and tesseract for ocr

```
import { Controller, Get, Param, Post, Res, UploadedFile, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportService } from './passport.service';
import { FileInterceptor, MulterModule } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import Tesseract from 'tesseract.js';
import { editFileName, imageFileFilter } from './passport.utils';

@Controller('passport')
export class PassportController {
    constructor(private passportService: PassportService) { }

    @Post('upload')
    @UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor('uploadedImage', {
            storage: diskStorage({
                destination: './uploads',
                filename: editFileName
            }),
            fileFilter: imageFileFilter,
        }),
    )
    async uploadImage(@UploadedFile() file): Promise<any> {
        const response = {
            originalname: file.originalname,
            filename: file.filename,
        };
        try {
            Tesseract.recognize('../../uploads/' + response.filename, "eng", {
                logger: (m) => console.log(m),
            }).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
                return {
                    person: text,
                };
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                error,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the tesseract code I'm able to get the uploaded file response mentioned in the code but using tesseract for ocr gives error

Comment: Please share the error that is coming from Tesseract

Comment: Error comes from the catch block. The error is an empty object.

Comment: You should be logging the error to see what's happening. The `Error` class does not have enumerable properties, so when `JSON.stringify(error)` happens (under the hood in the response code), all you'll get back is `{}`. The error isn't empty, just the enumeration of it is.

Comment: Cannot read property 'recognize' of undefined